# How to update the app in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I created an app in Android Studio v0.3.7.

The app works fine on v 4.3 but crashes on 4.1.2 as reported by some users of the app.

I found that the adding a prepopulated sqlite database function is the code that crash the app on 4.1.2

Now I want to change this function to rectify the problem and publish it as an update on Google Play.

Anyone has a tutorial or link on this please?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Post your stack trace and relevant code. We cannot guess at your problem.

Comment: @Kuffs its not. Problem i'm facing, i just want to know how to update my app on google play store without making a whole new app and package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just rectify your problem normaly, and then export a `Signed APK` with the exact same keystore you used before, otherwise it won't update the app on google play, you will then have to remove and put a whole new one, the problem here your users won't be notified of the update

Comment: So just change whatever code i want and then sign the apk and upload it again in play store? @user2427819

Comment: exactly, just remember to increment your version number in the manifest, once you do this, your users will automaticly get a notification to donwload the update version, or even better if the user has an automatic update, it will update automaticly

Comment: Thanks for your help... Much appreciate it :)